# Regex expression in the program doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, filereader

I'm writing a program that will read a text file and throw an error if the text has any characters which are not whitespace nor a word character. The regex expression seems correct but it doesn't work.

For example these texts:

- `Harry Potter$`
- `Harry Potter`
- `&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&uvuoyvouyvouyvouyvouyv78789******`

displays in the console without an error

I checked regex expression on https://regexr.com/ as well

Double \ is needed because otherwis,e I get an error Illegal escape character

```java
import java.io.*;

public class DZ {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println(method());
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean compare(char wrt) {
        String str = "[^\\s\\w]";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == wrt) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static StringBuilder method() throws Exception {
        int data;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/rachel_green/Documents/1.txt");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        while ((data = fr.read()) != -1) {
            if (compare((char)data)) {
                throw new Exception("Wrong file format");
            } else {
                str.append((char) data);
            }
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over each character of your regex expression and comparing it to a character from your source text?

Comment: What do you think `if(str.charAt(i) == wrt)` does? What makes you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a `String` with a `char` and you are iterating over the String holding your RegEx - which doesn't make sense:

```
public static boolean compare(char wrt){
    String str = "[^\\s\\w]";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){ //why are you diong this?
        if(str.charAt(i) == wrt) //you are checking every char of the regex agains the input char!
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instead, you could do this:

```
public static boolean compare(char wrt){
    return (wrt + "").matches("[^\\s\\w]");
}
```

Also, it may be a good idea to just stop reading the file the first time you find an invalid character. Otherwise it doesn't really make sense that you're checking each single `char` instead of the whole file content (like `content.matches(".*[^\\s\\w].*")`. Only throw your Exception once and `break;` the loop reading the file then!

Comment: `could be changed to "[\\S\\W]"` that would make regex match every non whitespace (as `\W` is subset of `\S`). Notice that `[^\\s\\w]` is like `not(\s OR \w)` which if you want to use `\S` and `\W` according to de Morgan's law should look like `not(\s) AND not(\w)` so more like `[[\S]&&[\W]]` (we can drop inner brackets `[..]`). What `[\\W\\S]` represents is `not(\w) OR not(\s)`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked:) I used this "[^\\w\\s]" in the regular expression though.

Comment: @Pshemo You are right, thank you for pointing this out. I should have thought about this twice. Removed from the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you are iterating for each char, instead you can match each line in the input file with pattern.

```
public static boolean compare(String wrt)
{
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\\w]");

    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(wrt);
    return matcher.find();
}

public static StringBuilder method() throws Exception
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/rachel_green/Documents/1.txt");

    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (compare(line))
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong file format");
        }
        else
        {
            str.append(line);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Hope this helps.